# Comparación entre arreglos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Espero puedan ayudarme con el siguiente problema.

El lenguaje con el que estoy trabajando es JavaScript.

Tengo 1 arreglo como este en donde estoy manejando horas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y Tengo un segundo arreglo el cual está conformado por una secuencia de horas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y busco un tercer arreglo que sea mi resultado en el cual mi arreglo 2 omita cada uno de los valores que tengo en el arreglo 1

Esperaría que mi resultado quedara de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el proceso que estoy utilizando actualmente, pero al hacer la iteración en ambos arreglos, el resultado me repite cada uno de los valores del arreglo2

```js
let arreglo1 = [ 6, 8, 10, 12, 2, 4 ];

let arreglo2 = [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18 ];

let arreglo3 = [];

arreglo2.forEach( element => {
      
      // console.log(element);

      arreglo1.forEach( horasOcupadas => {

        if ( element == horasOcupadas ) {

          // OMITIR HORAS

        } else {

          // console.log(element);

          arreglo3.push( element );

        }
        
      });

    });

    console.log( arreglo3 );
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: ¿Podría cambiar las imágenes por texto?

Comment: @JuanFelipeRubiano Listo !

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Listo, ya agregue un código que pueden ejecutar. Gracias por su ayuda !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo podrías trabajar haciendo un filter en el segundo arreglo, en el cual filtraras todos los números que no sean incluidos el primer arreglo.

Quedaría algo así:

```
const array1 = [6, 8, 10, 12, 2, 4];
const array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18];
const filteredArray = array2.filter((x) => !array1.includes(x));
```

O si lo que buscas es que sea compatible con IE11

```
var array1 = [6, 8, 10, 12, 2, 4];
var array2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18];
var filteredArray = array2.filter(function (x) {
  return !!!~array1.indexOf(x);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jesus ! Me funcionó